# Earth's surface radiation

Tags: energy, radiation, earth

**Earth's surface radiation**

I have been researching Earth's energy balance at various latitudes and have posted my work so far on Wordpress at https://hotgas.club with the title "Earth's Radiative Energy Balance, Land Surface Temperatures and Outgoing Longwave Radiation".
In order to make further progress I need to know what proportion of the energy radiated from Earth's **land surface** escapes directly to space without any absorption by the atmosphere, except of course the energy of the atmospheric window.  This could perhaps be called "spare energy", for ease of any replies.
I have thoroughly searched the internet for help without any success.
Helpful comments would be gratefully received.
Eddie Banner

Comment: A search for "atmospheric IR absorption curve" lists a lot of results.  Here's one: https://www.acs.org/content/acs/en/climatescience/atmosphericwarming.html

Comment: https://www.weather.gov/jetstream/energy has some energy balance info.